# ImportError: No module named pip when trying to install packages

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, package, pip

Have a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10 with PyCharm and when setting up the python interpreter I selected 'install setuptools', then 'install pip'. Now if I try and do anything with pip I get the following:

```
  ciaran@ciaran-desktop:~/pycharm/bin$ pip
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.4.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 357, in load_entry_point
   """Does the package's distribution contain the named metadata?"""
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2394, in load_entry_point

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2108, in load

  ImportError: No module named pip
```

I have tried on python 2.7.5 and 3.3.2 and both yield the same results.

Edit: The above output is from the terminal. PyCharm outputs the following:

```
Error: Python package management tool 'pip' not found
```

Comment: Maybe you need to activate your virtual environment?

Comment: did you try "sudo easy_install pip"? Anyway, you should use virtualenv: http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that on Ubuntu, pip will not always set read and execute permissions for the modules it installs. My solution is to always run this shell script:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rX /usr/lib/python*/dist-packages/
sudo chmod -R a+rX /usr/local/lib/python*/dist-packages/
sudo chmod a+rX /usr/bin/*
sudo chmod a+rX /usr/local/bin/*
```

Comment: It didn't work for me, I just downloaded get-pip.py and reinstalled pip.

Comment: In my case I had to run the reinstall from command line: python get-pip.py

Comment: @Yuhen Maybe the latest versions of pip have fixed the problem?

Answer (score 12):

Download the file get-pip.py from the pip-website (http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/installing/).
Open the terminal, cd in to the folder where you placed *get-pip.py*
and run:

> sudo python3 get-pip.py

Open pycharm and install desired package...

Answer (score 0):

I came here after getting crazy with "no module named serial" despite having pyserial installed with both pip3 and pip tools (at least I assumed that).

On my system (Tumbleweed) I have both python (2.7.18) and python3 (3.8.12), along with pip and pip3 tools. My assumption was that
pip and pip3 are different, just as python and python3 are.

However, it turned out that pip and pip3 was identical and it only installed modules for python3. I realized this only because python -m pip install pyserial returned "no module named pip" (despite pip was running standalone). A pip --version revealed that it was for python3 as well. A really weird combination!

In my case the solution was to install python2-pip via zypper/yast. After that, pip takes care for the installation of python2 modules (despite printing a deprecation warning about itself) and python -m pip now also works as expected.

Finally, pip install pyserial gave me the serial module for python2 that was required to compile/upload some Arduino esp32 stuff. I add these extra bits to cover the 20+ questions about "No module named serial" elsewhere which likely fail for the same reason in many cases.