# Disappearing pip

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

Why the module has been installed but not seen?

```
foo@bar:~/PycharmProjects/my$ virtualenv env
New python executable in /home/foo/PycharmProjects/my/env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
foo@bar:~/PycharmProjects/my$ source ./env/bin/activate
(env) foo@bar:~/PycharmProjects/my$ pip install django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pavel/PycharmProjects/my/env/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: No module named pip

(env) foo@bar:~/PycharmProjects/my$ which pip
  /home/foo/PycharmProjects/my/env/bin/pip
```

Comment: Why do you `source ./env/bin/activate` when your virtualenv is already activated? Try not to do this and see?

Comment: Why do you think it was already activated?

Comment: @Ivegotaquestion because of this line `(env) foo@bar:~/PycharmProjects/my$ source ./env/bin/activate`, (env) indicates that you have already activated env and trying to do same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named pip when trying to install packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391580/importerror-no-module-named-pip-when-trying-to-install-packages)

Comment: @Kjjassy: sorry, I was replacing my real username with foo@bar, this is where this (env) appeared.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already activated your virtualenv then deactivate it

```
(env)foo@bar:~/PycharmProjects/my$ deactivate
```

and try to create virtualenv with different name

```
foo@bar:~/PycharmProjects/my$ virtualenv venv
```

then activate virtualenv with this commands

```
foo@bar:~/PycharmProjects/my$ source venv/bin/activate
```

Now it should look like this

```
(venv) foo@bar:~/PycharmProjects/my$
```

And finally you can install packages

```
(venv) foo@bar:~/PycharmProjects/my$ pip install django
```

Comment: Done. Absolutely the same result -  "No module named pip"