# Permission issues while using and installing Python packages

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-14.04, pycharm

How to get rid of the permission issues while using and installing Python packages?

When I am trying to install any package using the PyCharm interpreter configuration, it says:

> Error: Python packaging tool 'pip' not found

I am sure that pip is already installed on my Ubuntu machine as I installed it at first using:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using a virtualenv or your global python? Check if your Pycharm is configurated correctly (so, if you use a virtualenv configure it to use it, [check here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/adding-existing-virtual-environment.html))

Go to `Project settings` > select your project and in the `Python interpreter` select your python directory

Can you try to execute `pip` in your terminal and see if it work? (Try `pip install Django`)

Comment: no iam not using a virtualenv, and the configurations i think, is good, the main problem is the permission on linux that stopping the packages from installing.

Answer (score 0):

**try install pip with:**

`sudo apt install python-pip`

**or install with easy_install**

`easy_install pip`

**also can install package with:**

`easy_install packagename`

see this https://askubuntu.com/questions/748264/error-python-packaging-tool-pip-not-found

**if it not work you can try it:**

`sudo chmod -R a+rX /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
sudo chmod -R a+rX /usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/`

Source https://stackoverflow.com/a/22423673/4941927

Comment: i tried this solution but giving me permission error, coz these folders are system folder. I tried with root permission to override that but also i got error.

Answer (score 0):

Use commands below to get pip installed:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | sudo python
sudo easy_install pip
```

Comment: it's already installed but package installer in pycharm not recognizing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python3, make sure to install `python3-pip` instead of `python-pip`.

`sudo apt-get install python3-pip`